# [FIXED, Roboflow exported CoCo Dataset mistake]YoloV5 cropping image into tiles with overlap (image + bbox)

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I have images that are 4928x3280 and I'd like to crop them into tiles of 640x640 with a certain percentage of overlap. The issue is that I have no idea how to deal with the bounding boxes of these files in my dataset as I've found this paper,(http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPRW_2019/papers/UAVision/Unel_The_Power_of_Tiling_for_Small_Object_Detection_CVPRW_2019_paper.pdf), but not code or so referring to how they did this. There are some examples on the internet that actually have the yoloV5 tiling but without overlap like this(https://github.com/slanj/yolo-tiling) one.

Does anyone know how I could make this myself or if someone has an example of this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a ready to go library to make possible tiling and inference for yolov5, there is SAHI:

<https://github.com/obss/sahi

You can use it to create tiles with related annotations, to make inferences and evaluate model performance.

Comment: I'm actually using YOLOR but it uses the Annotation like in YoloV5. Will this still work? :)

Comment: From what i can see, it's impemented in yolov5, yolox, detectron 2 and MMDetect,  so i don't know if it will work with yolox. The question was related to yolov5, you can try :D

Comment: Correct! But thanks anyway! I'll definitely give it a shot once I get to it again! i'll comment after I've tried it.

Comment: I got the tiling to work but I'm having a weird error when starting to train that something is out of bounds. I noticed that in my data.yaml file there is an extra class that wasn't there before. I used the COCO to YoloV5 exporter provided by the sahi but somehow class 0 is now "Components" which shouldn't be there. Any fix for this? :) (I might ask this question on the github issues thing)

Comment: I'm sorry but for that kind of work I use other libraries, so I can't tell you what went wrong and it's also a different question from the original one, as you said try asking on github :D.

Comment: No problem! Found the issue that my original dataset got an extra one, so now I introduced more spaghetti to the mix and seems to do the job (for now). And it's beginning to train! Stupid mistake. Thanks for the link and the help! :)

Comment: Nice work, remember to accept the answer, if resolve your problem :D

Comment: would be nice If I actually had that option- was looking for it yesterday.. 

[edit] found, stupid me